# Wildcard redirects on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create some redirect rules with wildcards but it seens that is not working.

```
Redirect 301 ^/nl//producten/(.*)/(.*) https://www.mysite.eu/lighting/$1/$2
Redirect 301 ^/fr//producten/(.*)/(.*) https://www.mysite.eu/fr/lighting/$1/$2
Redirect 301 ^/de//producten/(.*)/(.*) https://www.mysite.eu/de/lighting/$1/$2
Redirect 301 ^/en//producten/(.*)/(.*) https://www.mysite.eu/en/lighting/$1/$2
```

i want to redirect all producten to lighting.

Any ideea why this is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified rules on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^nl\/\/producten\/(.*)\/(.*)$ https://www.mysite.eu/lighting/$1/$2  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/\/producten\/(.*)\/(.*)$ https://www.mysite.eu/$1/lighting/$2/$3   [R=301,L]
```